# Solving ODE ${dV \over dt} + \frac{1}{\tau} V = f(t) = Ae^{j \omega t }$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For solving ${dV \over dt} + \frac{1}{\tau} V = f(t) = Ae^{j \omega t }$, Wikipedia says the solution is $V_0e^{-t/\tau} +A\frac{1}{j\omega +1/\tau} \left( e^{j \omega t} - e^{-t/\tau}\right)$.

But I get a different solution when I try solving it in a standard way. I do not have factor $A\frac{1}{j\omega +1/\tau}e^{-t/\tau}$. Why do we need this factor as the solution for the above ODE?

Comment: Did you take into account the condition $V(0)=V_0$ ?

Comment: "I get a different solution when I try solving it in a standard way" Please show your try.